# Is there an XPath to find nodes beneath a certain pattern?

Tags: python, regex, xml, xpath

I'm trying to write an xpath to find xml nodes with descendants that follow a specific pattern. For example, if I have the following xml:

```
<While>
  <Condition>
    <ID val="shouldLoop"/>
  </Condition>
  <Assign>
    <ID val="StringVariable1"/>
    <Parens>
      <Parens>
        <String val="StringLiteral"/>
      </Parens>
    </Parens>
  </Assign>
  <Assign>
    <ID val="StringVariable2"/>
    <String val="StringFigurative"/>
  </Assign>
  <Assign>
    <ID val="StringVariable3"/>
    <Add>
      <String val="StringLiteral"/>
      <String val="StringFigurative"/>
    </Add>
  </Assign>
</While>
```

I would like to get the first two of the three "Assign" nodes, based on them having a child node that's a "String" node nested within 0 or more "Parens" tags.

Is there an xpath that'll accomplish this similarly to how with regular expressions something like "(Parens/)*String" would match both "String" and "Parens/Parens/String"?

Comment: `//Assign[String|Parens//String]` will find `Assign` with a `String` child or with a `Parens` child with any `String` descendant. `<Parens><BadCrud><String>...` will also match, so its not exact.

Answer (score 0):

Try below `XPath` and let me know the result

```
//Assign[//Parens[String] or String][position()<3]
```

Comment: This xpath appears to be matching all Assigns with String or Parens/String nodes as descendents and returning the first two. If the Assign nodes in the example XML were in a different order, I'd want it still to return the Assigns with StringVariable1 and StringVariable2, but not StringVariable3.  
I'm looking for an xpath that will return the Assigns with nothing or only Parens between them and their String descendant node. The Add node for StringVariable3 breaks that pattern, so it should be excluded, but the rest should match.

Comment: Could there be something like `<some><Parens><String/><Parens><some>`? You don't want to match this also, right?

Comment: Right.     <Assign><some><Parens><String/><Parens><some></Assign> wouldn't be matched.